# Custom control structure with two blocks

Tags: scala

I'm entirely new to Scala and while reading some tutorials and documentation, I experimented with defining custom control structures.

So I tried to implement an implicit class `MyBoolean` that provides a `?` method with two parameter lists. The first parameter is a block that gets executed if `MyBoolean` is true, the second gets executed if `MyBoolean` is false.

Here is an example of how the syntax of the resulting control structure should look like:

```
true ? {println("true")} {println("false")};
```

so essentially just a simple if-else statement implemented as a method on Boolean.

Here is my implementation:

```
object Test extends App {
    implicit class MyBoolean(val value: Boolean) {
        def ? (body1: => Unit)(body2: => Unit){
            if (value) body1;
            else body2
        }
    }

    override def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
//      true ? {println("true")} {println("false")}; //--> compiler error
      true.? {println("true")} {println("false")}; // works fine...
    }
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that I get the following compiler error with the intended syntax (in Eclipse):

> missing arguments for method ? in class MyBoolean; follow this method
>   with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function

It only works if I explicitly add the dot `.` before the method `?`.

Shouldn't the dot be optional in Scala when calling methods? Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn't the dot be optional in Scala when calling methods?

Sort of, but that's not exactly accurate.

In these cases, that's true:

- `a.b(c)` can be written as `a b c`
- `a.b(c, d)` can be rewritten as `a b (c, d)`.

From the [language spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) section 6.12.3, Infix Operations:

> The right-hand operand of a left-associative operator may consist of several arguments enclosed in parentheses, e.g. *e op e<sub>1</sub>, …, e<sub>n</sub>*. This expression is the interpreted as *e.op(e<sub>1</sub>, …, e<sub>n</sub>)*.
>
> A left-associative binary operation *e<sub>1</sub> op e<sub>2</sub>* is interpreted as *e<sub>1</sub>.op(e<sub>2</sub>)*.

But there is no corresponding rule for expressions of the form `a.b(c)(d)`. I'm not really sure why, though. It seems to me that `a b {c} {d}` would be a perfectly reasonable way to write that.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the weirdest wrinkles in Scala syntax.  You can still use point-free style with multiple argument lists *but you have to group the object, method, and first argument list using parentheses* (?!)

```
(true ? {println("true")}) {println("false")}
```

works just fine.

Why does it work this way?  It is rather convenient with the `/:` and `:\` fold symbols; then you can group your first element together with the collection it's supposed to run through.

For everything else it is questionable at best.

Regardless, you're stuck with either parentheses or a dot.

Answer (score 1):

The dot's optional when calling *1-parameter* methods, but that syntax doesn't work for a 2-parameter method, even when curried (except as @RexKerr suggests if you bracket it).

You might be able to get it working by doing "manual" currying: write a one-parameter method that returns an object with an apply:

```
class PartiallyApplied(value: Boolean, body1: => Unit) {
  def apply(body2: => Unit) = if (value) body1; else body2
}

class MyBoolean...
  def ? (body1: => Unit) = new PartiallyApplied(value, body1)
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it results in the same problems - i.e. one must still at the dot before the method. Anyway: +1 for otherwise correct answer.